# How to use curve_fit from scipy.optimize with a shared fit parameter across multiple datasets?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

Assuming I have a fit function `f` with multiple parameters, for example `a` and `b`. Now I want to fit multiple datasets to this function and use the same `a` for all of them (the shared parameter) while `b` can be individual for each fit.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

# Fit function
def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

# Datasets
x = np.arange(4)
y = np.array([x + a + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(x)) for a in range(3)])
```

So we have 4 x values and 3 datasets of 4 y values each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to concatenate the datasets and use an adjusted fit function.

In the following example, this happens inside the new fit function `g` with `np.concatenate`. The individual fits for each dataset are also done so we can compare their graph to the concatenated fit with the shared parameter.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


# Create example datasets

x = np.arange(4)
y = np.array([x + a + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(x)) for a in range(3)])
print("x =", x)
print("y =", y)


# Individual fits to each dataset

def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

for y_i in y:
    (a, b), _ = curve_fit(f, x, y_i)
    plt.plot(x, f(x, a, b), label=f"{a:.1f}x{b:+.1f}")
    plt.plot(x, y_i, linestyle="", marker="x", color=plt.gca().lines[-1].get_color())

plt.legend()
plt.show()


# Fit to concatenated dataset with shared parameter

def g(x, a, b_1, b_2, b_3):
    return np.concatenate((f(x, a, b_1), f(x, a, b_2), f(x, a, b_3)))

(a, *b), _ = curve_fit(g, x, y.ravel())
for b_i, y_i in zip(b, y):
    plt.plot(x, f(x, a, b_i), label=f"{a:.1f}x{b_i:+.1f}")
    plt.plot(x, y_i, linestyle="", marker="x", color=plt.gca().lines[-1].get_color())

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
x = [0 1 2 3]
y = [[0.40162683 0.65320576 1.92549698 2.9759299 ]
 [1.15804251 1.69973973 3.24986941 3.25735249]
 [1.97214167 2.60206217 3.93789235 6.04590999]]
```

Individual fits with three different values for `a`:

[image: Figure 1]

Fit with shared parameter `a`:

[image: Figure 2]