# Using curve_fit to estimate common model parameters over datasets with different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, curve-fitting

I am working on a curve fitting problem, where I have the intention of estimating shared model parameters globally over several datasets of unequal size. I started working from the code in the link below, where a common a-parameter for a linear regression y = a*x + b is estimated on three different y-vectors with a common x-vector. [How to use curve_fit from scipy.optimize with a shared fit parameter across multiple datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231516/how-to-use-curve-fit-from-scipy-optimize-with-a-shared-fit-parameter-across-mult)

I managed to adapt the code sample to the more general case, with three different x-vectors, one corresponding to each y data vector. However, when I want to extend it further to work also for datasets of unequal size, I run into the following error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.".

Please find the code sample below. Any help is highly appreciated!

Cheers

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
[0.3, 1.3, 2.3]]

y = [[-0.80216234,  1.41125365,  1.42565202,  2.42567754],
[ 1.34166743,  1.29731851,  2.98374731,  3.32110875],
[ 1.71398203,  3.29737756,  3.81456949]]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)


def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b


def g(x, a, b_1, b_2, b_3):
     return np.concatenate((f(x[0], a, b_1), f(x[1], a, b_2), f(x[2], a, b_3)))

(a, *b), _ = curve_fit(g, x, y.ravel())

for x_i, y_i, b_i in zip(x, y, b):
    plt.plot(x_i, f(x_i, a, b_i), label=f"{a:.1f}x{b_i:+.1f}")
    plt.plot(x_i, y_i, linestyle="", marker="x",  color=plt.gca().lines[-1].get_color())
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

See below for the code of the working example with multiple x-vectors of equal size:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
 [0.3, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3]]

y = [[-0.80216234,  1.41125365,  1.42565202,  2.42567754],
 [ 1.34166743,  1.29731851,  2.98374731,  3.32110875],
 [ 1.71398203,  3.29737756,  3.81456949, 4.25]]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)


def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b


def g(x, a, b_1, b_2, b_3):
    return np.concatenate((f(x[0], a, b_1), f(x[1], a, b_2),     f(x[2], a, b_3)))

(a, *b), _ = curve_fit(g, x, y.ravel())

for x_i, y_i, b_i in zip(x, y, b):
   plt.plot(x_i, f(x_i, a, b_i), label=f"{a:.1f}x{b_i:+.1f}")
   plt.plot(x_i, y_i, linestyle="", marker="x",     color=plt.gca().lines[-1].get_color())

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you also show the **working** example for multiple x-vectors of equal size? The problem is, that numpy can neither parse `x` nor `y` as a matrix, since they do not have equal length. So it does not parse as a `n \times m` matrix, but as a `n` dimensional array of **list objects**.

Comment: Dear André,

Thanks for your response, I will edit the post and add the code of the working example for multiple x-vectors of equal size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I agree that the implications for least-squares fitting are rather complicated... some quick thoughts:

- can you be certain that the obtained `b` parameters are equally valid if they are estimated from different-length datasets?
- the more b-parameters you get the more uncertain their estimates will be since you only optimize the combined fit-performance and not each individual fit-performance
- I'm also uncertain how well the numerical evaluation of the jacobian will work in such a case... it might be worth implementing a custom `jac` function that evaluates the jacobian in an exact way
- ... anad I'm sure there are more problems which I'm currently not aware of :D

Nevertheless, you can of course trick `scipy.optimize`to do what you want...
However, you have to go 1 step deeper and use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` directly rather than using the higher-level `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function.

This way you can alter the way how the residuals are calculated to accept datasets of different lengths.

... here's a quick-and-dirty implementation of how it could work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

x = [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
     [0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
     [0.3, 1.3, 2.3     ]]

y = [[-0.80216234, 1.41125365, 1.42565202, 2.42567754, 3, 4],
     [ 1.34166743, 1.29731851, 2.98374731, 3.32110875],
     [ 1.71398203, 3.29737756, 3.81456949            ]]


def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b


def fun(parameters):
    # separate a and b parameters
    a, *b = parameters

    # calculate function-results based on a shared a- and variable b- parameters
    res = (f(xi, a, bi) for (xi, bi) in zip(map(np.array, x), b))

    # calculate the residuals
    errs = []
    for i, j in zip(res, map(np.array, y)):
        errs += (i - j).tolist()
    return np.array(errs)


# set start-values
start_values = (1, 1, 2, 3)
# do the fit
a, *b = least_squares(fun, start_values).x

for x_i, y_i, b_i in zip(map(np.array, x), y, b):
    plt.plot(x_i, f(x_i, a, b_i), label=f"{a:.1f}x{b_i:+.1f}")
    plt.plot(x_i, y_i, linestyle="", marker="x", color=plt.gca().lines[-1].get_color())

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: fit resutls]

Comment: Dear Raphael,

Thanks for showing this quick and elegant implementation! Could you clarify what
.x means/does in the line 
a, *b = least_squares(fun, start_values).x?

Comment: hey, `least_squares` returns a `OptimizeResult` object... and the `.x` property will just give you the obtained parameters-vector! I guess it's best explained by the doc ;-)  (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html)

Comment: Great, thanks man! Why does the err need to be converted to a list in the line? 
`errs += (i - j).tolist()`

Comment: @bessie because we need a flat list of residuals in the end (you can also collect a list of residual-vectors and then concatenate them, but this would also copy the data so I thought simply appending the values right away might be similarly fast and efficient...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cant create an `numpy.array` from a ragged list. To recast as a `np.array` all the dimensions must match i.e you cannot have an empty *column* entry as this makes no sense to Numpy.

In your case you havent defined an entry for one of the *columns* in the array (ie 3 entries in the last *row* when the other *rows* have 4 entries). Numpy simply will not let you do this as its a numerical package that depends on rectangular well definded arrays to do computation.

Comment: what would be a proper way to define the data structure and feed it to the curve_fit algorithm in this case? List objects do not have a 'ravel' attribute?

Comment: @bessie your code isnt getting as far as the curve fit. To fit all the data sets to the model at the same time then they need to be the same shape. In a physical system this would mean that the missing elements would be `0` i.e. you would need to pad out your input data with `0`s where an entry was missing. This may of course have consequences on the fit of the data.

Comment: In my code, the idea is that each line in the x-array represents a vector containing the times at which a property was measured of a sample, while in the y-array, each line represents a vector containing the observed values. In practice, it can be that for different samples, the sampling times are different & that there are less or more sampling times depending on the sample. However, it should still be possible to estimate the model parameter of e.g. linear growth in common for the different samples?

Comment: Yes you can, you just cant do it like you have proposed. For indepenent samples you would need to do individual regressions then you would get a range of possible parameters.  From there you could make a choice of a fixed `a` & then redo the regression again I guess. But unfortunately the method you are attempting will only work if ALL the inputs are the same shape.

Comment: That is indeed unfortunate! Could you provide some code to put me in the right direction?

Comment: Basically fit your linear model to each of your sample sets individually (if they are of different sizes) then look at the parameters you get, choose a value for the parameter you want to set based on the range of parameters you get from your fits. Then fix that parameter & rerun the regressions to get your other parameters. I appreciate you're a new user to SO but it really is not the kind of place where you are going to get soemone to do this for you. We'll happily answer questions about specific problems, as above. But no-ones gonna write your code for you.

Comment: The aim is not to get someone to write the code, that would be useless as this minimal example, is far away from the code I need which involves fitting ODE solutions to data, but still the principle remains the same. I don't see why the fitting the model to the separate datasets would result in getting a common best estimate for the parameter "a". Somehow, I should be able to define a global cost function to be minimized and I was thinking this is exactly what curve_fit is supposed to do, so I am surprised it cannot handle this kind of input where the datasets have different sizes.

Comment: @bessie the whole field of optimization is too massive to be having this conversation on SO but if your are interested in something more powerfull than the `curve_fit` method then I suggest having a look though the [Scipy Optimize library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) for something that fits (pun intended) your problem better, good luck.