# How to resolve the conda issue: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels

Tags: python, conda, symfit

I am try ing to install symfit on a MacBook Pro M1 using miniforge, for processor compatibility as `pip3 install symfit` results into errors. However, when running `conda install -c conda-forge symfit`, I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - symfit

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

When doing so, I find that symfit is available in the conda-forge channel! Why can't it be installed from the command line?

Comment: This package is not currently being built for **osx-arm64** (the M1 platform). From what I can tell there should not be a major difficulty in adding such a build. I created [an issue for this request on the `symfit-feedstock`](https://github.com/conda-forge/symfit-feedstock/issues/15).

Answer (score 1):

At the time of the question, [the Conda Forge feedstock for **symfit**](https://github.com/conda-forge/symfit-feedstock) was not building for **osx-arm64** platform. After [an issue being filed](https://github.com/conda-forge/symfit-feedstock/issues/15) on the feedstock, [one of the maintainers updated the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/symfit-feedstock/pull/16) to generate `noarch` builds (platform agnostic). So, starting with version 0.5.3, what OP attempted should just work.

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge symfit
```

The lesson here is: Conda Forge is an open platform, so if you find something not being built, please reach out to the feedstocks or submit a Pull Request. The community depends on active feedback from users to improve.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
**this answer was posted before OP changed to use the correct `conda install -c conda-forge symfit` command!**

- turns out at the time of question `symfit` has no build for "OSX_arm64" which is why the command fails

---

because `conda install` will try to install the module from the default channel...
you have to explicitly tell conda to use conda-forge!

```
conda install -c conda-forge symfit
```

-> check the doc!! https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had already tried that, without success it results in the same error!

Comment: Exactly the same as above, I have edited my initial post tot show the complete message.

Comment: it might be because of your processor.... there's only `OSX-64` wheels available... none for `OSX-arm64`   (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/symfit)    but I have no experience with those kind of things...

Comment: just to check.... `numpy` for example has an explicit `OSX-arm64` wheel   (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy)

Comment: if you search for a replacement-library to do your fitting... you might want to have a look at `scipy.optimize`  (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)   (It's most probably the library that symfit draws it's fit-functions from....)

Comment: This is not helpful because the package is not available for the OP platform (**osx-arm64**).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Raphael! I have to fit ODE-solutions to measurements of observations over time for several samples. The problem is that the datasets have different length, which is why I cannot use curve_fit as discussed in one of my previous post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545110/using-curve-fit-to-estimate-common-model-parameters-over-datasets-with-different. I am afraid that I will have use Scipy.optimize instead of an existing more user-friendly package.

Comment: @merv: I have successfully installed Scipy on my system using MiniForge! here is the post I used to do so: https://towardsdatascience.com/new-m1-who-dis-677e085baffd.

Comment: @bessie sorry if I caused confusion: I was referring to `symfit` not being available. `scipy` happens to be a dependency of `symfit` and yes it is already being built on Conda Forge for your platform.