# Using curve_fit for multiple x,y datasets with shared parameters

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, curve-fitting, array-broadcasting

I came around with [fineboot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231517/15465872) about using scipy's *curve_fit* for multiple data sets with shared parameters and I'm facing the following problem:

Basically I would like to use two [x,y] data sets:

```
x = np.random.rand(3,4)
y = np.random.rand(3,4)
```

while his answer deals with only one dimensional array *x* :

```
x = np.arange(4)
y = np.array([x + a + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(x)) for a in range(3)])
```

In the answer, he concatenates the dataset with shared parameters

```
def g(x, a, b_1, b_2, b_3):
    return np.concatenate(f(x,a,b1), f(x,a,b_2), f(x,a,b_3))
```

and then applies the *curve_fit*:

```
(a, *b), _ = curve_fit(g, x, y.ravel())
```

from [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> Parameters:

> xdata -> array_like or object the independent variable where the data is measured. Should usually be an M-length sequence or an (k,M)-shaped array for functions with k predictors, but can actually be any object.

when I try to apply the array_like object `x = np.random.rand(3,4)` in *curve_fit* I get:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,4) (12,)

thanks!

Comment: It's probably also relevant if you share what *you* are doing. That is, your function and fitting code (in the form of a minimum but relevant example). Especially given that both your dependent and independent variables are two-dimensional.

Comment: the most simple solution is not to use `curve_fit` but `least_squares` knowing that the first is a wrapper for the last anyhow. Plus the fact that 3D data is not straight forward on `curve_fit` either.

Comment: it's really straighforward what I'm trying to do:
fit an equation using a couple of [x.y] datapoints. but my x variables are not linearly spaced.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, it was just a dummy mistake:

The answer is to replace:

```
def g(x, a, b_1, b_2, b_3):
    return np.concatenate(f(x,a,b1), f(x,a,b_2), f(x,a,b_3))
```

with

```
def g(x, a, b_1, b_2, b_3):
    return np.concatenate(f(x[0],a,b1), f(x[1],a,b_2), f(x[2],a,b_3))
```